# Error in BASH shell script - Using Variables as References

Tags: bash, shell, variables, scripting

Two questions about problems I'm having writing up a BASH script that uses variables. I cannot for the life of me figure this out and it is KILLING me.

1) I have the following code.

```
pdir=/media/The_Enforcer/ICA_Doug/Participants/RS1
cd ${pdir}

for subject in * ; do
    subdir=${pdir}/${subject} ;
    cd ${subdir} ;
    subj= echo ${subject} | head -c-9
    3dAFNItoNIFTI -prefix ICA/cleanRS_NII_${subj} RSFC_LFF_rall_${subj}+orig ;
    cd ${pdir} ;
done
```

${subject} is a subject ID which is ########.results. For example: 1R101U1A.results. Basically my code cd's me into that directory in which is a file called RSFC_LFF_rall_1R101U1A+orig which I want to process via the code line that starts with 3dAFNItoNIFTI. Obviously I can't use ${subject} variable in that code line because it would attempt to find the file RSFC_LFF_rall_1R101U1A.results+orig which does not exist. So to fix this I made a new variable called ${subj} which, via the echo pipeline, basically cuts off the last 9 letters of ${subject} which, in effect, removes the .results. When I do this and echo ${subj} it gives me 1R101U1A which is exactly what I want.

However, the line of code that starts with 3dAFNItoNIFTI errors with the following:

```
FATAL ERROR: Can't open dataset 'RSFC_LFF_rall_+orig'
```

I have tried declaring the ${subj} variable like, five different ways (including using head, tail, cut, and colons) and I still get this error.
What am I doing wrong?

2) In attempting to define ${subj} in numerous ways I also tried this method:

```
${subj}= ${subject:0:8}
```

When I did this, the final bracket refused to close - i.e. the closing bracket did not turn the color of the opening bracket and when I attempted to run the script I got an error at that line saying 'command not found.' I checked my syntax against the examples I was following and it looks fine? Am I missing something here?

Comment: there is at least one problem that you have an extra space in `subj= echo ${subject} | head -c-9` after the `=`. Also you should write `subj=$(echo ${subject} | head -c-9)` to properly do the assignment (in fact if you just remove the extra space, it gives exactly the `command not found` error you are quoting). In general you should consider running your script through a spellchecker, e.g. http://www.shellcheck.net/#

Comment: Holy crap it was the space!? Oh my God I feel like an idiot. Thank you so much; I honestly probably wouldn't have thought to even check that on my own. Additionally I had no idea shellcheck was a thing so I've got that bookmarked now.

But yes, that fixed my problem.
Quick question: Is the way you have the assignment (with the $( before echo) a better way for any particular reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
cd "/media/The_Enforcer/ICA_Doug/Participants/RS1"

for subject in * ; do
    cd $subject
    subj=${subject%.results}
    3dAFNItoNIFTI -prefix ICA/cleanRS_NII_${subj} RSFC_LFF_rall_${subj}+orig
    cd ..
done
```

`${subject%.results}` removes `.results` from the end of the string.
See [Shell-Parameter-Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

Comment: This is a much more elegant solution than what I was doing, it seems. I obviously know enough to use wildcards but not enough to remove things. Thank you for your answer, it will come in handy in the rest of these scripts.